# Set unique id for each object in Python

Tags: python, design-patterns

I need to make class, for which each instantiated object will have unique id (simply incremented counter). For now, all 3 objects(b, b1, b2) shares one A.__COUNTER variable.

```
class A(type):
__COUNTER = 0

def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    setattr(cls, "id", A.__COUNTER) 
    A.__COUNTER += 1

    return type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)


class B():
    __metaclass__ = A

    def __init__(self):
       self.id

b = B()
b1 = B()
b2 = B()

print(b.id, b1.id, b2.id) -> (2, 2, 2)
```

Seems like I am digging in wrong direction

P.S. **SOLVED**

Sorry, guys, I did not mentioned that there can be couple classes which should share same id sequence.
There are bunch of solutions, here how I solved it

```
class A(type):
__COUNTER = 0
def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    obj.setId(A.__COUNTER)
    A.__COUNTER += 1

    return obj

 class B():
    __metaclass__ = A

    def setId(self, id):
        self.id = id 

class C():
   __metaclass__ = A

   def setId(self, id):
       self.id = id 

b = B()
b1 = B()
b2 = B()
c = C()
b3 = B()

print(b.id, b1.id, b2.id, c.id, b3.id) -> (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: You need to have the id in the A class ? If not why don't use a simple array ?

Comment: whats wrong with this method?

Comment: All object refers to one value 
print(b.id, b1.id, b2.id) -> (2, 2, 2)
but I need 1, 2, 3, ...

Answer (score 4):

You can just use a class variable instead:

```
class B ():
    __lastId = 1

    def __init__ (self):
        self.id = B.__lastId
        B.__lastId += 1
```

```
>>> [B().id for _ in range(10)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

As described in [What is a metaclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python), a meta class is the class of a class, whereas you just want to modify the actually instantiated objects of a single type. So there’s no need to go deep into the metaclass complexity level here.

Comment: Would make more sense to call it `__next_id` in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Well, all objects in Python already have a unique id

```
>>> id("a string")
140588614961168
```

But if you want a separate counter, the method you use should work.
More information on WHY you want this could help though.

Comment: Yeap, I know about id().
I just need to make something similar (assign unique id for each instance of the class)

Answer (score 1):

A good solution depends on the use case. I've provided a very generic one.

`IDAssigner` is a factory that sticks an ID onto everything is creates. Create an instance of `IDAssigner` for a new pool of IDs. You call an instance of `IDAssigner` passing the class to instantiate as the first argument, followed by arguments for the class's `__init__` method.

```
from itertools import count


class IDAssigner(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._next_id = count()

    def __call__(self, klass, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = klass(*args, **kwargs)
        setattr(obj, 'id', next(self._next_id))
        return obj


class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value


create = IDAssigner()
foo_1 = create(Foo, 'Hello')
foo_2 = create(Foo, 'World')
print(foo_1, foo_1.id)
print(foo_2, foo_2.id)
```